# How to allow a website to be accessed without www

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

For now, I have these DNS records which points to my web server :

```
example.com.       IN    A    123.123.123.123
www.example.com    IN    A    123.123.123.123
```

I am wondering if it is good practice to have an A record for "example.com" itself. I was told to use a wildcard address (implying it was better practice), but I don't know how to do that.

I also have this in `httpd.conf` :

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
```

Is there a *standard* way of allowing a site to be accessed without the leading www.?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a wildcard record unless you need it. In this case, it sounds like you don't.

In this situation, I typically create two records like this:

```
example.com.       IN    A      123.123.123.123
www.example.com    IN    CNAME  example.com
```

This way you only need to update a single record if your IP address changes.

With regards to your VirtualHost config, I typically like to do the reverse of what you are doing:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

In all honesty, this doesn't matter a whole lot, though.

Comment: Thank you! So, you are telling me that it is not wrong to have an A record for "example.com" itself as I was told.

Comment: @Gradient - no, there's nothing wrong at all with having two `A` records. It just means that you need to update two records when IP addresses change instead of only needing to update a single record.